# Some users in Azure AD can't get email in access_token

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, access-token

We have configured an App Registration for the web app in Azure, for Auth Code flow.

API permission provided for Microsoft Graph email only and it works for users with Identity MicrosoftAccount. But other users with Identitiy appname.onmicrosoft.com in the same Azure AD is not received email.

Here is Manifest

```
{
    "id": "7e7416d3-4a71-4f64-b226-09a5a1f0f721",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
    "addIns": [],
    "allowPublicClient": false,
    "appId": "6885b85e-1599-46f5-b5ea-e0539c1f2a72",
    "appRoles": [],
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
    "createdDateTime": "2023-04-17T08:28:30Z",
    "description": null,
    "certification": null,
    "disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
    "groupMembershipClaims": "None",
    "identifierUris": [],
    "informationalUrls": {
        "termsOfService": null,
        "support": null,
        "privacy": null,
        "marketing": null
    },
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "logoUrl": null,
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "name": "CO1 Sandbox",
    "notes": null,
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": false,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
    "oauth2Permissions": [],
    "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
    "optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [],
        "accessToken": [],
        "saml2Token": []
    },
    "orgRestrictions": [],
    "parentalControlSettings": {
        "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
        "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
    },
    "passwordCredentials": [
        {
            "customKeyIdentifier": null,
            "endDate": "2023-10-14T08:29:05.715Z",
            "keyId": "<edited>",
            "startDate": "2023-04-17T08:29:05.715Z",
            "value": null,
            "createdOn": "2023-04-17T08:29:10.676232Z",
            "hint": "SLo",
            "displayName": "Base"
        }
    ],
    "preAuthorizedApplications": [],
    "publisherDomain": "<edited>.onmicrosoft.com",
    "replyUrlsWithType": [
        {
            "url": "https://<edited>/oauth2-callback/custom",
            "type": "Web"
        }
    ],
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "<edited>",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "samlMetadataUrl": null,
    "signInUrl": null,
    "signInAudience": "AzureADMyOrg",
    "tags": [],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}
```

access_token from MicrosoftAccount user response

```
{
  "aud": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/cf0b35d0-4348-488c-9067-7cfd8ca7b4e3/",
  "iat": 1681903293,
  "nbf": 1681903293,
  "exp": 1681908838,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "AXQAi/8TAAAAqToQUeN9uGt68KcWyyTrD3EWSZnTjqMxC/d76+QGudoUJyff0cV8OQ5D2FZGPYsNtAFbiqNi+4soTKZYtyqrZY/EC8rwoa14qxzhdYGo2lbyoQLJKipqPOPCVxHQThkwxcoYE6qPd+kGayieAxaH5A==",
  "altsecid": "1:live.com:00034001E55087B5",
  "amr": [
    "pwd",
    "mfa"
  ],
  "appid": "6885b85e-1599-46f5-b5ea-e0539c1f2a72",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "email": "arthurmiko@gmail.com",
  "family_name": "Miko",
  "given_name": "Arthur",
  "idp": "live.com",
  "ipaddr": "91.195.157.108",
  "name": "arthurmiko",
  "oid": "ed609ec9-3e88-4ca2-b0cc-cf4ca21484d2",
  "puid": "10032002977A43D4",
  "rh": "0.AVIA0DULz0hDjEiQZ3z9jKe04wIAAAAAAAAAwAAAAAAAAAC6AE8.",
  "scp": "email",
  "sub": "aklfjIVFj_eQKI3Q-fvqdrGFmqDfMddnEwxwIVbua9U",
  "tenant_region_scope": "NA",
  "tid": "cf0b35d0-4348-488c-9067-7cfd8ca7b4e3",
  "unique_name": "live.com#arthurmiko@gmail.com",
  "uti": "XE64BKqMxUSoXF7tj9A-AA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

access_token from response for user created in Azure AD

```
{
  "aud": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/cf0b35d0-4348-488c-9067-7cfd8ca7b4e3/",
  "iat": 1681903443,
  "nbf": 1681903443,
  "exp": 1681908580,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "ATQAy/8TAAAAxiOx66AToXUIlRpNgqSAotDdvwVrmSV5wZz0dp0xGdBFjk+m/yrO9Sf1GL+4C9Nh",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "appid": "6885b85e-1599-46f5-b5ea-e0539c1f2a72",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "ipaddr": "91.195.157.108",
  "name": "co1sandbox",
  "oid": "d48807d1-819f-46ba-9e40-b4b6639abfee",
  "puid": "1003200296F1C5E6",
  "rh": "0.AVIA0DULz0hDjEiQZ3z9jKe04wIAAAAAAAAAwAAAAAAAAAC6AD0.",
  "scp": "email",
  "sub": "UgaqZBHsaBySu8x4dYFKf3wP_K7F2pQ96aHlHZ7owmQ",
  "tenant_region_scope": "NA",
  "tid": "cf0b35d0-4348-488c-9067-7cfd8ca7b4e3",
  "unique_name": "co1sandbox@<edited>.onmicrosoft.com",
  "upn": "co1sandbox@<edited>.onmicrosoft.com",
  "uti": "ZQinedt5MUSUPUDAtrBKAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Page of properties for co1sandbox user

[image]

I've already tried to add different sorts of API permissions and claims, change request for authorization with adding scope, change user role in app, tried another supported account types but all useless.

I expect to receive in access_token email that specified in user properties in Azure AD.